# ColdFusion/ASP split URL handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, coldfusion, url-routing

I am working on a new ASP.NET MVC (IIS 7) application that needs to hang off the URL of an existing group of ColdFusion applications.  The URL hosts a series of applications and is of the form:

```
http://myapps.com/allApps/<appNumber>/<appViews>
```

ColdFusion is currently handling all the applications on this URL.  I need the new ASP.NET application to use the same URL format but have a specific <appNumber>.  So for example, ColdFusion handles:

```
http://myapps.com/allApps/1/<appViews>
http://myapps.com/allApps/2/<appViews>
http://myapps.com/allApps/3/<appViews>
http://myapps.com/allApps/4/<appViews>
```

New ASP.NET app needs to handle:

```
http://myapps.com/allApps/5/<appViews>
```

I know how to use ASP routing to send the requests to my ASP app controller once my app is getting the requests, but I don't know how to tell IIS to send the specific URLs to my application so they are not processed by ColdFusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have IIS set up to pass ASP.NET pages to ColdFusion for processing, it should not matter.

Comment: So are you saying I just set up my application-specific routing in my global.asax and the rest will be handled by default by ColdFusion?

Comment: Not necessarily 'the rest'. IIS has to be told what files are to be handled by ColdFusion (I believe this can be done with the web Server Configuration Tool that is part of the ColdFusion install) and which are to be handled by ASP.NET (never used ASP.NET, so I am not sure how IIS gets this info). For example: files that have a files extension of .cfm will be processed by ColdFusion not ASP.NET. I have worked on sites that processed ColdFusion, PHP and ASP.NET and have had no issues as long as the handlers are set correctly.